# I am creating listfield to store all messages from blackberry mail box, but getting stuck in display messages as a list field

Tags: blackberry, email

I am creating listfield to store all messages from blackberry mail box, but getting stuck in display messages as a list field.

Comment: Can you please explain where exactly are you getting "stuck"? can you post some code so  we can see what's wrong/missing ? I guess, if I understand correctly, that you have a collection of messages (array of strings or whatever) and you're unsure on how to draw them as list items?

Comment: Yes, That what I am getting stuck at.  I am unable to transfer the mails to listfield

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/mail/Store.html) is probably what you are looking for to retrive the message from the BlackBerry mail store.

[This](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListField.html) is the API for your ListField, which you will be able to fill with the info from the mail store.